# Testing a file download using Selenium - python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I write automation tests in Selenium and use python and the chrome browser.
I need to write a test that downloads a file (from a link ) and checks that the file has been downloaded. And if possible, the test checks the file type.
How can I write this?

I managed to download the file using click(), but I don't know how to check if the file has been downloaded.

Comment: Do you need to actually download the file during each test run? Or do you want to mock up the download?

Comment: I can mock up the download.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `download.default_directory` to the `ChromeOptions` and instantiate the `webdriver.Chrome` with the options object. All the downloads made with this instance will be stored in the `download.default_directory`.

To make the test platform-agnostic you can use the `tmp_path` fixture provided by `pytest`, it will create a temporary directory for the downloaded files. But make sure you specify `str(tmp_path)` as the `download.default_directory` for the `ChromeOptions`.

Consider the following example, you can run it with `pytest test_download.py`:

```py
# test_download.py

import os
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass
from pathlib import Path

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver


@dataclass
class Chrome:
    driver: webdriver.Chrome
    downloads: Path


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def chrome(tmp_path):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option(
        "prefs",
        {
            "download.default_directory": str(tmp_path),
        },
    )

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    yield Chrome(driver=driver, downloads=tmp_path)

    driver.quit()


def test_download_file(chrome: Chrome):
    filename = "sample4.csv"
    chrome.driver.get(f"https://filesamples.com/samples/document/csv/{filename}")

    # Wait for the file to download, adjust if needed
    time.sleep(1)

    # Check if the file has been downloaded
    assert filename in os.listdir(chrome.downloads)
```